# SQL Azure Connector for REST/Swagger API - marketplace? package settings?

Tags: sql-server, rest, azure, swagger

I'm trying to create a (Swagger based) REST API for my SQL Azure database.  I'll be using it in Logic Apps, PowerApps, and other places.

For some reason I can't find the Microsoft SQL Connector when searching in the Azure marketplace.  Is there some trick to finding this?  I have a pay-as-you-go subscription and I'm not having any issue with creating other services.

I was able to create a connection to my Azure SQL database via Logic Apps Designer, and it allows me to trigger queries and other database operations.

But when I edit the SQL Connection, I can't seem to find the Package Settings, which is apparently where I need to be in order to generate the Swagger API for CRUD operations (according to the examples I've been reading).

I also tried to configure this connection within abn API APP, but again couldn't find the "package settings" where you set up the CRUD operations.

Is there a trick to finding package settings and/or configuring the SQL Connector for a REST API?  Or are all of the public examples outdated and something has changed?

Comment: What is it that you need to do beyond what you can do with the OOB connector to Azure SQL Database? The OOB connector allows you to do a lot of CRUD operations already.

Comment: I'm trying to do this sort of thing - [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yavnika26techblog/2016/08/08/working-with-logic-apps-and-microsoft-sql-connector-on-microsoft-azure/)  It seems to indicate that you can find the SQL Connector in the Azure Marketplace (which I can't), and use it (from package settings) to generate a CRUD-based REST API, and also the Swagger definition.  From there it looks like you can set up a Swagger + API trigger within a Logic App and map to those CRUD operations.  I've seen a few published examples along these lines.  No doubt there are other ways...

Comment: The link you provided seems to indicate a scenario where an SQL table is monitored for changes and actions are taken accordingly, including CRUD operations.  This can be done easily with Flow and the OOB connector.  Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do that cannot be done OOB?

Comment: What I'm specifically trying to do...  is access CRUD functions from a SQL Table based on a REST API that includes a Swagger definition.  There are a number of articles (including the one I linked) that indicate this is possible with the Azure SQL Connector as described.  Perhaps the SQL Connector functionality has changed and this is no longer possible.  I'm aware that there are a number of other ways to get the end result, as there always is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an Azure function to connect to an SQL Database as [described here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup)
Then you can add the API definition as [described here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition)
You can then use it in PowerApps/Flow as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/app-service-export-api-to-powerapps-and-flow), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-powerapps-scenario), and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-flow-scenario).
All are relatively fresh articles and should work.

Comment: Thanks - helpful articles.  I've been exploring Functions as well, and they look like a good alternative to wrap my data access and expose it within Logic/PowerApps/Flow.